# PHP Myadmin exporting to tab separated .csv file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export my table in tab separated .csv file. I done with phpmyadmin. But it gives me some wrong values in my .csv file. For example in my database title is

```
Rocky Boot  Men's    8" Desert Tan S2V Boot Style: 101
```

In csv file it's stored as

```
Rocky Boot  Men's    8"" Desert Tan S2V Boot Style: 101
```

I want same values in .csv file as in database.

seetings I followed while exporting .css file from phpMyadmin:

```
Format:CSV
Columns separated with:\t
Columns enclosed with:"
Columns escaped with:"
Lines terminated with:AUTO
Replace NULL with:
```

Where I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the escaped quote (`""`).  That's because you have "Columns enclosed with" and "Columns escaped with" set to `"`.  You could use a different character if you like, but a .csv file has to have some way to distinguish between characters in strings and those that are separators.  For example, the difference between:

```
foo    bar    test
```

(3 columns with tab separator) and

```
"foo    bar"    test
```

(2 columns with tab separator).

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked that your columns be enclosed with a double-quote("), it's normal that phpMyAdmin doubles a double-quote found inside a column, producing "".